# Returning multiple SERIAL values from Posgtres batch insert

Tags: postgresql

Im working with Postgres, using `SERIAL` as my primary key. After I insert a row I can get the generated key either by using '`RETURNING`' or `CURRVAL()`.

Now my problem is that I want to do a batch insert inside a transaction and get ALL the generated keys.

All I get with `RETURNING` and `CURRVAL` is the last generated id, the rest of the result get discarded.

How can I get it to return all of them?

Thanks

Comment: something like this:
INSERT INTO AutoKeyEntity (Name,Description,EntityKey) VALUES ('AutoKey 254e3c64-485e-42a4-b1cf-d2e1e629df6a','Testing 5/4/2011 8:59:43 AM',DEFAULT)
returning EntityKey ;
INSERT INTO AutoKeyEntityListed (EntityKey,Listed,ItemIndex) VALUES (CURRVAL('autokeyentity_entityKey_seq'),'Test 1 AutoKey 254e3c64-485e-42a4-b1cf-d2e1e629df6a', 0)
   ,  (CURRVAL('autokeyentity_entityKey_seq'),'Test 2 AutoKey 254e3c64-485e-42a4-b1cf-d2e1e629df6a', 1)
   ,  (CURRVAL('autokeyentity_entityKey_seq'),'Test 3 AutoKey 254e3c64-485e-42a4-b1cf-d2e1e629df6a', 2)
;

Comment: several like that one all together, so insert with returning, some inserts using currval, and again the same

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `RETURNING` with multiple values:

```
psql=> create table t (id serial not null, x varchar not null);
psql=> insert into t (x) values ('a'),('b'),('c') returning id;
 id 
----
  1
  2
  3
(3 rows)
```

So you want something more like this:

```
INSERT INTO AutoKeyEntity (Name,Description,EntityKey) VALUES
('AutoKey 254e3c64-485e-42a4-b1cf-d2e1e629df6a','Testing 5/4/2011 8:59:43 AM',DEFAULT)
returning EntityKey;
INSERT INTO AutoKeyEntityListed (EntityKey,Listed,ItemIndex) VALUES
(CURRVAL('autokeyentity_entityKey_seq'),'Test 1 AutoKey 254e3c64-485e-42a4-b1cf-d2e1e629df6a', 0),
(CURRVAL('autokeyentity_entityKey_seq'),'Test 2 AutoKey 254e3c64-485e-42a4-b1cf-d2e1e629df6a', 1),
(CURRVAL('autokeyentity_entityKey_seq'),'Test 3 AutoKey 254e3c64-485e-42a4-b1cf-d2e1e629df6a', 2)
returning EntityKey;
-- etc.
```

And then you'll have to gather the returned `EntityKey` values from each statement in your transaction.

You could try to grab the sequence's current value at the beginning and end of the transaction  and use those to figure out which sequence values were used but [that is not reliable](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-createsequence.html#AEN61833):

> Furthermore, although multiple sessions are guaranteed to allocate 
>   distinct sequence values, the values might be generated out of
>   sequence when all the sessions are considered. For example, with a
>   *cache* setting of 10, session A might reserve values 1..10 and return
>   `nextval=1`, then session B might reserve values 11..20 and return
>   `nextval=11` before session A has generated nextval=2. Thus, with a
>   *cache* setting of one it is safe to assume that `nextval` values are
>   generated sequentially; with a *cache* setting greater than one you
>   should only assume that the `nextval` values are all distinct, not
>   that they are generated purely sequentially. Also, `last_value` will
>   reflect the latest value reserved by any session, whether or not
>   it has yet been returned by `nextval`.

So, even if your sequences have *cache* values of one you can still have non-contiguous sequence values in your transaction. However, you might be safe if the sequence's *cache* value matches the number of INSERTs in your transaction but I'd guess that that's going to be too large to make sense.

**UPDATE**: I just noticed (thanks to the questioner's comments) that there are two tables involved, got a bit lost in the wall of text.

In that case, you should be able to use the current INSERTS:

```
INSERT INTO AutoKeyEntity (Name,Description,EntityKey) VALUES
('AutoKey 254e3c64-485e-42a4-b1cf-d2e1e629df6a','Testing 5/4/2011 8:59:43 AM',DEFAULT)
returning EntityKey;
INSERT INTO AutoKeyEntityListed (EntityKey,Listed,ItemIndex) VALUES
(CURRVAL('autokeyentity_entityKey_seq'),'Test 1 AutoKey 254e3c64-485e-42a4-b1cf-d2e1e629df6a', 0),
(CURRVAL('autokeyentity_entityKey_seq'),'Test 2 AutoKey 254e3c64-485e-42a4-b1cf-d2e1e629df6a', 1),
(CURRVAL('autokeyentity_entityKey_seq'),'Test 3 AutoKey 254e3c64-485e-42a4-b1cf-d2e1e629df6a', 2);
-- etc.
```

And grab the `EntityKey` values one at a time from the INSERTs on `AutoEntityKey`. Some sort of script might be needed to handle the RETURNING values. You could also wrap the `AutoKeyEntity` and related `AutoKeyEntityListed` INSERTs in a function, then use [`INTO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) to grab the `EntityKey` value and return it from the function:

```
INSERT INTO AutoKeyEntity /*...*/ RETURNING EntityKey INTO ek;
/* AutoKeyEntityListed INSERTs ... */
RETURN ek;
```

Comment: The thing with returning with mutltiple values is that I need the proper currval for the secondary table, so I cant put all the primary table inserts in a single one

Comment: @Nicolas: Oh, I just saw the difference between `AutoKeyEntity` and `AutoKeyEntityListed`, got a bit lost in the "wall of text". Then why not grab the `AutoKeyEntity` values one at a time from the INSERTs and leave the `AutoKeyEntityListed` INSERTs as they are?

Comment: it works well if I go one by one (`AutoKeyEntity` and `AutoKeyEntityListed` with currval for reference, returning the generated key), but what Im trying to accomplish here is some performance tuning doing a batch insert. Might not be possible tho.

Comment: You might be able to wrap it up in a function to group the INSERTs into your two tables together.

Comment: The very important thing here is that the order of returned values [is not guaranteed](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAL9jXCHVg0CVEke%2BeiMjYA_UBffnacGYEN9Psb1h-kFw8QLxrw%40mail.gmail.com) to be the same as in the query

Answer (score 8):

you can pre-assign consecutive ids using this:

```
SELECT setval(seq, nextval(seq) + num_rows - 1, true) as stop
```

it should be a faster alternative to calling `nextval()` gazillions of times.

you could also store ids in a temporary table:

```
create temporary blah (
  id int
) on commit drop;

insert into table1 (...) values (...)
returning id into blah;
```

in postgres 9.1, can able to use CTEs:

```
with
ids as (
insert into table1 (...) values (...)
    returning id
)
insert into table2 (...)
select ...
from ids;
```

Answer (score 3):

In your application, gather values from the sequence :

```
SELECT nextval( ... ) FROM generate_series( 1, number_of_values ) n
```

Create your rows using those values, and simply insert (using a multiline insert). It's safe (SERIAL works as you'd expect, no reuse of values, concurrent proof, etc) and fast (you insert all the rows at once without many client-server roundtrips).

Comment: This is NOT SAFE!  It has a very real race condition.  Try this, open up two psql terminals, and create a sequence, then run the command select nextval('myseq') from generate_series(1,1000000); in both windows at the same time.  You will get numbers that are not in sequence.

Comment: Obviously there is no guarantee that the numbers will be without "holes", but that's normal and expected, and both concurrent accesses will get different, unique, sequence numbers. If the purpose is to grab a wholesale lot of sequence values to use in a bulk insert, what is the problem ?

Comment: Oh crap, you're right.  I thought you were grabbing them from the generate series.  derp.  sorry.

Comment: You made me doubt ;) generate_series() is so useful, I use SELECT DISTINCT (random()*foo)::INTEGER FROM generate_series() all the time to fill test tables with believable stuff...

Answer (score 1):

Replying to Scott Marlowe's comment in more detail :

Say you have a tree table with the usual parent_id reference to itself, and you want to import a large tree of records. Problem is you need the parent's PK value to be known to insert the children, so potentially this can need lots of individual INSERT statements.

So a solution could be :

- build the tree in the application
- grab as many sequence values as nodes to insert, using "SELECT nextval( ... ) FROM generate_series( 1, number_of_values ) n" (the order of the values does not matter)
- assign those primary key values to the nodes
- do a bulk insert (or COPY) traversing the tree structure, since the PKs used for relations are known

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to do this.  Use currval(), use returning, or write a stored procdure to wrap either of those methods in a nice little blanket that keeps you from doing it all in half client half postgres.

```
Currval method:
begin;
insert into table a (col1, col2) values ('val1','val2');
select currval('a_id_seq');
123  -- returned value
-- client code creates next statement with value from select currval
insert into table b (a_fk, col3, col4) values (123, 'val3','val4');
-- repeat the above as many times as needed then...
commit;

Returning method:
begin;
insert into table a (col1, col2) values ('val1','val2'), ('val1','val2'), ('val1','val2') returning a_id; -- note we inserted three rows
123  -- return values
124
126
insert into table b (a_fk, col3, col4) values (123, 'val3','val4'), (124, 'val3','val4'), (126, 'val3','val4');
commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform a FOR LOOP and process records one by one. It might be less performant but it is concurrency safe.

Example code:

```
DO $$
  DECLARE r record;
    
  BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT id FROM {table} WHERE {condition} LOOP
      WITH idlist AS (
        INSERT INTO {anotherTable} ({columns}) VALUES ({values})
        RETURNING id
      UPDATE {table} c SET {column} = (SELECT id FROM idlist) WHERE c.id = {table}.id;
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```