# How to select a list of 100 next sequence values from a database

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, postgresql, sequence

```
select nextval ('mySchema.mySequence')
```

This command will return the next value of a sequence.

How can I get the next N values from a sequence in SQL?

My current setup uses postgreSQL, and Hibernate's native SQL queries, but any solution is appreciated.

Comment: What database product and version?

Comment: postgreSQL. Queries made from Hibernate, where I enter native SQL code. Ideally, this should be database-independent.

Comment: @iliaden - First, you should tag your question with Hibernate. Second, true database-independence is nearly impossible to achieve. The implementation (or lack of) of sequences for example vary widely among database products.

Comment: thanks - but any solution for this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: See answers from [Returning multiple SERIAL values from Postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875953/returning-multiple-serial-values-from-posgtres-batch-insert)

Comment: You could write a stored procedure nextvals(n) that accepts the count of sequential numbers desired and increments the store by that number.  That would guarantee the numbers are contiguous. How do you want those numbers to be returned? as 100 rows containing a single column? As a single row with two columns, the first and last number in the sequence? What purpose do you have in mind for it?

Comment: @j.w.r  - you posted the link to the working solution... Is there a way to mark a comment as the right solution? `SELECT nextval( 'mySchema.mySequence' ) FROM generate_series( 1, 100 ) n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link to an answer provided on a related question.
[How to select multiple rows filled with constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201170/how-to-select-multiple-rows-filled-with-constants/2201201#2201201)

The solution for Postgres, Oracle, and SQL Server are all different.

The Postgres solution is:

```
SELECT  l
FROM    generate_series(1, $n) l
```

In your case instead of `select l` you would `select nextval('mySchema.mySequence')`

Comment: that's an interesting approach, but I can't quite figure out how to make it 1) read from a sequence   2) set the sequence value to the last generated value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292199/query-several-nextval-from-sequence-in-one-satement might be how to do it in oracle...

Answer (score 3):

You can define your sequence with INCREMENT BY 100 and then, when you get your next value N using SQL just use values N + 1, N + 1, ..., N + 99 in your Java code.

Comment: I never know how many values I would need at once. 100 was for example. so this solution doesn't really apply.

Comment: @iliaden: Well, you should have some upper limit. If you are working with large amounts of data in Hibernate, you should be splitting it in batches with, say, 5000 records/objects limit. In that case INCREMENT BY 5000 would work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Please use this SQL query. 
**Note**: it will work only in case of Oracle.

```
select your_sequence_name.nextval from dual connect by level <= 100
```