# Query several NEXTVAL from sequence in one statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Basically, I need to query about a thousand NEXTVAL from a sequence. I can query them in a loop, or I can query them through a join with a reeeeeally big table.

Is there any less hacky way?

**Upd.**
Basically, I have a schedule of operations on objects. Each object has either a generated UUID, or an ID from database. After I calculate an optimal schedule, I need to write it into DB, but every ID in the table HAS to be from a sequence. So I need to query some IDs from that sequence. The problem is that looping query is slow, since the DB is really far from me, and I can't just loose several seconds while executing dozens of queries in a loop. So I need to query all those new IDs in one query.

Comment: Also NB that you may need/want to use a large fetchsize to avoid still having an RTT per row returned: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17331855/32453

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use this:

```
select your_sequence.nextval
from (
   select level 
   from dual 
   connect by level < 1000
);
```

Comment: also see a slightly modified version of this in Florin Ghita's response, as well.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that the results may or may not be contiguous?

Answer (score 27):

Depends on what you want to do with them.

If you insert them in a table, you can unse seq.nexval in the insert query. (As explained here: [How can I insert multiple rows into oracle with a sequence value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228221/how-can-i-insert-multiple-rows-into-oracle-with-a-sequence-value))

If you use them in a loop, you can fetch them in that loop.

What do you want to do with them?

As I know, you can't fetch multiple values from sequence.

**UPDATE:**
a_horse_with_no_name's aswer can be improved like this:

```
select your_sequence.nextval
from dual 
connect by level < 1000
```

:)

Answer (score 3):

My (H2) unit test database did not support "connect by", so I had to come up with something else:

```
    with temp_id_table (lvl) as 
       (select 1 as lvl from dual 
        union all 
        select lvl+1 
          from temp_id_table 
          where lvl < 1000) 
    select sequence_name.nextval 
    from temp_id_table;
```

Comment: Both this and the "connect by" approach only return one nextval row when I use jdbc to run this... Although when run on Oracle SQL Developer, I get the correct number of rows.

Answer (score -4):

```
select sequence_name.nextval
from dual
connect by level < number of values you want to print;
```

Comment: This is identical to other answers.

Comment: This will give you **one less** than "number of values you want to print"