# Selecting a sequence NEXTVAL for multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle10g, linked-server

I am building a SQL Server job to pull data from SQL Server into an Oracle database through a linked server. The table I need to populate has a sequence for the name ID, which is my primary key. I'm having trouble figuring out a way to do this simply, without some lengthy code. Here's what I have so far for the SELECT portion (some actual names obfuscated):

```
SELECT (SELECT NEXTVAL FROM OPENQUERY(MYSERVER, 
    'SELECT ORCL.NAME_SEQNO.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL')), 
     psn.BirthDate, psn.FirstName, 
     psn.MiddleName, psn.LastName, c.REGION_CODE
FROM Person psn
LEFT JOIN MYSERVER..ORCL.COUNTRY c ON c.COUNTRY_CODE = psn.Country
```

MYSERVER is the linked Oracle server, ORCL is obviously the schema. Person is a local table on the SQL Server database where the query is being executed.

**When I run this query, I get the same exact value for all records for the NEXTVAL. What I need is for it to generate a new value for each returned record.**

I found this similar question, with its answers, but am unsure how to apply it to my case (if even possible): [Query several NEXTVAL from sequence in one statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292199/query-several-nextval-from-sequence-in-one-satement)

Comment: How is this `select` query transferring data into an Oracle database?

Comment: I think the OP meant `from` not `into`.

Comment: It's just doing a simple insert. I didn't include that part of the code because I didn't feel it to be necessary to the question.

Comment: I don't believe I said `into` anywhere in the question. EDIT: I see where you're confused. Yes, it will ultimately insert into an Oracle table, but I only posted the `select` portion because that's what I need to know for now. The `insert` is irrelevant.

Comment: A quick scan or search would have yielded "from SQL Server ***into*** an Oracle database" (emphasis mine).

Comment: I'm not sure why the rudeness is warranted. I very clearly stated that I was posting the `SELECT` portion of the code. The only thing I'm concerned about is getting a new sequence value for all returned records.

Comment: I bolded the most important part of the question. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: What rudeness are you talking about? Andomar asked how your query was selecting *into* an Oracle database. I was merely explaining why they might have come to that conclusion. Saying "I don't believe I said `into`" is pretty obnoxious when it's in the first line of the question, isn't it?

Comment: How table DUAL associated with Person or COUNTRY?

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko it's not. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table

Comment: I didn't intend to be rude with that comment; I apologize if that's what was taken by it. I've found one way to do this by using a table on the Oracle side of things and selecting the sequence value from that, but that's unfortunately not an option, as the table I'm selecting from is on the SQL Server, and I have to `OPENQUERY` the Oracle db for the sequence number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to iterate through all the records and set the ID value individually. Messy and slow, but it seems to be the only option in this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

put it in a SQL scalar function. Example:

```
CREATE function [dbo].SEQ_PERSON() 
returns bigint as
begin
    return
    (   select NEXTVAL 
        from openquery(oraLinkedServer, 'select SEQ_PERSON.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL')
    )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy Just Use a CURSOR to Iterate with the code :

```
SELECT NEXTVAL AS SQ from OPENQUERY(MYSERVER, 'SELECT  AC2012.NAME_SEQNO.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL')
```

**So you can embed this select statement in any Sql statement, and Iterate by the CURSOR.**

PS:

```
DECLARE SQCURS CURSOR  
FOR SELECT (SELECT NEXTVAL AS SQ FROM OPENQUERY(MYSERVER, 
'SELECT ORCL.NAME_SEQNO.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL')), 
 psn.BirthDate, psn.FirstName, psn.MiddleName, psn.LastName, c.REGION_CODE
```

FROM Person psn
LEFT JOIN MYSERVER..ORCL.COUNTRY c ON c.COUNTRY_CODE = psn.Country

OPEN SQCURS 
FETCH NEXT FROM SQCURS ;

I hope that help