# how can you avoid a round trip time "once per row" for hibernate queries

Tags: hibernate

It appears that with a query I have, which returns 1000 rows, hibernate is taking *forever* to create a list from the return value of the query.  It seems that hibernate is taking one "round trip" per row, which, in my case, takes a long time.  Can this be avoided?  This is an oracle db, in my particular instance.  The query is just a list of 100 sequence id's, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/8292557/32453

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears that hibernate allows for setting a "fetch size" which allows to avoid the round trip time in this case.

ref: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/objectstate.html search for "fetchSize"

Here is how I ended up using it in my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">10000</property>
```

Now my 1000 row queries come back about 10x faster.  Nice.  I guess the default is a fetch size of 1, which requires a RTT for each row.