# OracleDataReader GetValue throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: oracle, getvalue

There is at least one other thread with this title or one very close to it but it was not quite like my specific implementation and I couldn't find my answer in it.
I have this code

```
<code>
List<string> lsRes = new List<string>();
OracleConnection conn = getOracleConnection();
try
{
    string sqlQuery = "select CTS.SEQ_BATCH_ID.nextval from dual connect by 
level <= " + seqCnt;
    conn.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    OracleDataReader dr;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
        lsRes.Add(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
}
catch(exception e)
{ 
</code>
```

I'm getting my InvalidOperationException on dr.GetValue(0). Any idea why? Sequence should be returning a number or numbers, I'm converting it/them to a string/strings, Should I be using GetOracleValue? There are no precompiler or compilation errors just in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which language that code is, but I think the issue could be the CONNECT BY clause. I doubt you can use that to do what you want out of that sequence. A sequence will return one value per execution. If you only have one value, there is nothing to CONNECT.

Edit: Whoops wasn't aware of the CONNECT BY trick for a sequence. So the SQL should run fine as long as you have permissions. Not sure what language that code you are using is, but I don't think this should be tagged as Oracle.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292199/query-several-nextval-from-sequence-in-one-statement

Comment: @pchancey Huh. I wasn't aware of that. Neat. In that case, I would suspect it's not an issue with Oracle, but the code that calls the Oracle.

Comment: Should be tagged as OracleDataReader but I lack the permissions to add that tag, language is c#

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve my problem with OracleDataReader but I did manage a work around.

```
List<string> lsRes = new List<string>();
OracleConnection conn = getOracleConnection();
try
{
    DataTable dtValue = new DataTable("ID");
    string sqlQuery = "select  CTS.SEQ_BATCH_ID.nextval from dual connect by level <= 
    " + seqCnt;
    conn.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    OracleDataAdapter orada = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    orada.Fill(dtValue);
    orada.Dispose();
    cmd.Dispose();

    if (dtValue != null && dtValue.Rows != null && dtValue.Rows.Count > 0 )
        foreach (var item in dtValue.Rows)
            lsRes.Add(((System.Data.DataRow)item).ItemArray[0].ToString());
}
catch
{
```